# MySQL advanced UPDATE query

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I want to set an image as a cover for the album and i do it by choosing it from a radio input that is in a do-while loop. I have put in images table a field named is_cover that takes 1 if the image is set as cover ,or 0 if not.

```
<input type="radio" name="cover" value="<?php echo $row_images['image_id']; ?>" <?php if($row_images['is_cover'] == 1){ echo "checked=\"checked\""; } ?> />
```

My question is how can i perform an update query that sets all images is_cover field to 0 and only the image selected gets the value 1.

What i'm trying to say is how can i achieve this:

```
$is_cover = $_POST['cover'];
$query = "
    UPDATE images 
    SET is_cover = 1 
    WHERE image_id = {$is_cover} 
          AND SET is_cover = 0 
    WHERE image_id <> {$is_cover}
";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick for you:

```
UPDATE images SET is_cover = CASE WHEN image_id = {$is_cover} THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
```

From my test:

```
mysql> select * from first;
+------+-------+
| id   | title |
+------+-------+
|    1 | aaaa  |
|    2 | bbbb  |
|    3 | cccc  |
|    4 | NULL  |
|    6 | ffff  |
+------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> update first set title = case when id > 4 then 'gggg' else title end;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 5  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from first;
+------+-------+
| id   | title |
+------+-------+
|    1 | aaaa  |
|    2 | bbbb  |
|    3 | cccc  |
|    4 | NULL  |
|    6 | gggg  |
+------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Cool solution. I didn't know how to do that. What is the benefit of this over two queries? Data integrity? Efficiency?

Comment: @AndyGroff It is a single query, in this case, not a huge benefit over two simple ones, but you can do a heck of a lot more with case statements.

Comment: Hi, i just found a small problem with your query. The update effects all rows in the database which is a problem, at least in my case. The update should effect only images that belong to a specific album. So in order to work the query correct, the update should effect all images that their album_id should match the album_id of the album they belong.

Comment: @Lykos22 You can add the `where someColumn=someVal and someOtherColumn=someOtherVal` in your update statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can run 2 Queries here one to set them all to 0 and then setting the one you selected to 1

Answer (score 0):

Execute these 2 queries:

```
$query = "UPDATE images SET is_cover = 0 WHERE image_id <> {$is_cover}";

$query = "UPDATE images SET is_cover = 1 WHERE image_id = {$is_cover}";
```

The first query sets all `is_cover` to zero. The second query sets `is_cover` to 1 for the selected image.